# I can't create tables with sqlite3 - My table "exists" in sqlite, but it doesn't show up in my actual database

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm creating a table called employees2, but I get the error "OperationalError: table employees2 already exists".

However, when I check in my actual database, there is no such table in my database.

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('Stocks.db')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute ('CREATE TABLE employees2 (name TEXT, surname TEXT, salary real)')

connection.commit()
```

Comment: How do you "check in the actual database" if the table exists?

Comment: Is the database not the database located in my IDE? In my case, SSMS?

Comment: No, Stocks.db is your database. I don't know what this should have to do with your IDE, or what SSMS is.

Comment: I was trying to connect to an existing table on my sql server, which has the database named as "Stocks". So, I thought that connection = sqlite3.connect('Stocks.db') would connect to that database. How could I connect to my already existing database then?

Is sqlite3 just a SQL server within python itself? Like how a DF is created only within the python ide?

Comment: SQLite is an in process database engine, you're creating a file called Stocks.db on your machine.  This has nothing with SQL Server, that would use some other API.

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE TABLE` has a `IF NOT EXISTS` clause precisely for this case:

https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/create-table-stmt.html

Comment: That's true, but won't solve their problem of trying to create a table in their actual database.